# Adding radiogroup dynamically with respect to an JsonArray size

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-recyclerview, radio-group

I have a json array within jsonArray and I need to add the number of radioButton in a radiogroup according to the inner array length. Kindly suggest me a way to do it. From the code I need to set the number of radiobuttons according to the the size of the  predefinedAnswersOptions array. Because the size of the array is variable not contant.

```html
"subServices": [
        {
            "id": 7,
            "questions": [
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "question": "Brand ?",
                    "isActiveQuestion": true,
                    "isOptionBased": true,
                    "isDescriptive": false,
                    "isSpecificQuestion": true,
                    "isGeneralQuestion": false,
                    "isMultipleSet": true,
                    "hasPriceList": true,
                    "hasQty": true,
                    "maxQty": 5,
                    "predefinedAnswersOptions": [
                        {
                            "id": 13,
                            "options": "Samsung",
                            "isActiveOption": true,
                            "isSpecificQuestion": true,
                            "isGeneralQuestion": false
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 14,
                            "options": "Sony",
                            "isActiveOption": true,
                            "isSpecificQuestion": true,
                            "isGeneralQuestion": false
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 8,
                    "question": "Installation/Repair ?",
                    "isActiveQuestion": true,
                    "isOptionBased": true,
                    "isDescriptive": false,
                    "isSpecificQuestion": true,
                    "isGeneralQuestion": false,
                    "isMultipleSet": true,
                    "hasPriceList": true,
                    "hasQty": true,
                    "maxQty": 5,
                    "predefinedAnswersOptions": [
                        {
                            "id": 30,
                            "options": "Installation",
                            "isActiveOption": true,
                            "isSpecificQuestion": true,
                            "isGeneralQuestion": false
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 31,
                            "options": "Repair",
                            "isActiveOption": true,
                            "isSpecificQuestion": true,
                            "isGeneralQuestion": false
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 9,
                    "question": "Type of TV ?",
                    "isActiveQuestion": true,
                    "isOptionBased": true,
                    "isDescriptive": false,
                    "isSpecificQuestion": true,
                    "isGeneralQuestion": false,
                    "isMultipleSet": true,
                    "hasPriceList": true,
                    "hasQty": true,
                    "maxQty": 5,
                    "predefinedAnswersOptions": [
                        {
                            "id": 19,
                            "options": "LCD",
                            "isActiveOption": true,
                            "isSpecificQuestion": true,
                            "isGeneralQuestion": false
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 20,
                            "options": "LED",
                            "isActiveOption": true,
                            "isSpecificQuestion": true,
                            "isGeneralQuestion": false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
```

Comment: recyclerview is what you need to dynamically add views.

Comment: In recyclerview there are certain information already displayed from the json array. But I need to add radio button dynamic with respect to the size of the inner array tagged by the name predefinedAnswersOptions.

Comment: add radio buttons to your view which you will recycle and in the OnBindViewHolder use if-else to make the radiobutton visible or gone.

Comment: but the size of the inner array is not fixed. Its value can cary from 1 to n. So I need a way to add it programatically by using the arraylist size of the inner array

Comment: use the constructor to send the size of the inner array. i would suggest you to iterate the json response using gson library. if you are using retrofit then gson serilization and deserialization is done seamlessly further simplifying your codes. with that you can send the entire json response to the constructor, having arraylist or whatever you need and then access the size of the arraylist.

Comment: here is a good tutorial for you. https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-recyclerview-cardview-tutorial/

Comment: I am using volley.

Comment: hmmm sorry bro. i am a devotee of retrofit due to its simplicity.

Comment: you can give retrofit a try. You will admire the simplicity.

Comment: i even use it in web which is in progress using spring boot.

Comment: Ok, so if I am using retrofit I need a json converter like GSON etc. In that case how I can approach with setting up the radio button programatically.

Comment: By dynamic if you mean to add radio buttons programmatically then it will be a mammoth task for you. Follow the approach that i have suggested. I have tried it before. I used a simple if-else to change the visiblity to GONE inside OnBindViewHolder.

Comment: Bro, adding radio button programatically is a easy task. I implemented it and it just 15-20 lines of coding. But the issue remains how I pass the indented arraylist value in oncheckedChanged.

Comment: create a sample project and try the retrofit way, given in the tutorial. then if it works then convert it to volley way.

Comment: Okay if atall in retrofit I want to access an arraylist within two datamodels. Like Someclass<DAtamodel> which gives an arraylist again someclass1<Datamodel1> and then again someclass2<Datamodel2> so, I can do that in the main activity